# How to either separate text and button for skew, or combine text and button?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have this following code that works, but I can't separate the text from the button.  For instance, when skewed, the text skews.  Any way to separate them?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
      <h2>Categories</h2>
        <div class="categories-">

          <% @categories.each do |cat| %>
            <%= link_to cat.name, listings_path(:category => cat), class: "btn btn-primary-2" %>
          <% end %>
      </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
 .categories- {
   padding-top: 30px;
   font-size: 30px;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 }
```

I then attempted doing this, which works, but the button itself when clicked, doesn't click to anything as it's not attached to the link.  Any way to attach it?

```
<div class="categories-">
      <% @categories.each do |cat| %>
        <div id="btn-text"><div id="btn-cat"><%= link_to cat.name, listings_path(:category => cat) %></div></div>
      <% end %>
  </div>
```

I was told you add  but that didn't work.

Here's the CSS:

```
 #btn-cat {
    transform: skew(-15deg);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  yellow, red) !important;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;

    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 16px !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }

  #btn-text {
    transform: skew(15deg);
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
```

How can I accomplish either one of those methods? The top one the text and button won't detach.  The bottom one, the button and text won't attach.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your controllers or routes I would have to guess it would have to be:

```
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
  <%= link_to cat.name, category_path(cat), class: "btn btn-primary-2" %>
<% end %>
```

But if you're not using the conventional restful routes, and your passing a model that doesn't correlate to the controller with same name type as class of your instance variable, you'll need to be more verbose.

```
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
    <%= link_to cat.name, controller: 'listings', action: 'show', id: cat.id, class: 'btn btn-primary-2' %>
 <%  end %>
```

The above should try to produce:

```
<a href="/listings/show/23" class="btn btn-primary-2">Category Name</a> 
# where 23 and Category name are repspective from the cat object.
```

[See documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) for the variations on how to use `link_to` helper

Comment: category isn't a path.  It's a model/table that's attached to listings.  I don't beleive i would be able to do it that way.  I think this is a CSS/html issue.  Then again, I will try this once i get back to that app tonight or tomorrow and ill update here

Comment: The rails convention for `link_to` helper will automatically try to convert the object type to it's show page.  But if you are not using the conventional REST routes you'll need something more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want separate the text from the button and use `#btn-cat` and `#btn-text` separately.

You can use:

```
<div class="categories-">
  <% @categories.each do |cat| %>
    <div id="btn-cat">
      <%= link_to listings_path(:category => cat) do %>
        <div id="btn-text"><%= cat.name %></div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Now, all the button it's a link :)

[image]