# Why is the color on my button dull, but on hover it isn't?

Tags: html, css

Here's the images normal vs hover: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44wq2.jpg
With the hover, the colors are correct.  When there isn't a hover the colors are dulled.

Here's my CSS:

```
.btn-primary-2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  crimson, red) !important;
  border: none !important;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  border-radius: 16px !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 10px 3px ;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding: 16px !important;

}

.btn-primary-2:hover, .btn-primary-1:focus, .btn-primary-1:active, .btn-primary-1.active, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary-1 {
    color: white !important;

    border: none; /*set the color you want here*/
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background: linear-gradient(to left, crimson, red) !important;
    font-weight: bolder !important;

}
```

View, just in case this is relevant:

```
<div class="categories-">

      <% @categories.each do |cat| %>
        <%= link_to cat.name, listings_path(:category => cat), class: "btn btn-primary-2" %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
```

Why's the color dulled like this but when hovered, is fine?

EDIT:

I have came to a theory and/or conclusion that the reasoning behind this dulling is because of the "btn" default from bootstrap which is what I am using.  The default buttons all darken when hovered.  I can only assume this is the reason because buttons i make without the assistance of bootstrap don't have this issue.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to override this     ?

Comment: Can you create a live example with the Code Snippet feature?

Comment: because of the loop, i won't be able to.  And i think that may be a part of why this is happening.  Here's a previous post, I was looking to avoid this issue (and allowing Skew without having text skewed) but i couldn't get the button and text to combine when clicked.  If i click on button, nothing happens.  only works when i click on the text within the button: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901191/how-to-either-separate-text-and-button-for-skew-or-combine-text-and-button/52902273?noredirect=1#comment92720152_52902273

Comment: so i came to the theory/conclusion that it's due to bootstrap.  i noticed all boostrap buttons are dulled by default so when you hover over them the color darkens.... would you or anyone here have any idea on how to over ride this?